# Unpacking jersey libraries in spring boot jar

Tags: java, spring, jersey, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-jersey

I have a project spring boot with a jersey dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I do a `spring-boot:run` all the context gets up perfect and everything works.

The problem comes when I make a packaging of that project with `mvn package`, because `requiresUnpack` not unpack the jersey depencencies. And this is necesary for this problem: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1468

Inside the pom.xml I use:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <requiresUnpack>
                    <!-- dependencies that I want to unpack -->
                    </requiresUnpack>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>          
    </build>
```

Then when I do `java -jar jarBoot.jar` the console output is:

```
2019-05-02 15:02:46.218 ERROR 17476 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : StandardWrapper.Throwable

org.glassfish.hk2.api.MultiException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Francesc\microservices git\sidecar-base\target\sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1009) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:975) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1067) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1059) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:78) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:264) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:187) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at com.micro.base.sidecarbase.SidecarApplication.main(SidecarApplication.java:13) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.ResourceFinderException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Francesc\microservices git\sidecar-base\target\sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:89) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:65) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.addResourceFinder(PackageNamesScanner.java:282) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.init(PackageNamesScanner.java:198) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:154) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:110) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.packages(ResourceConfig.java:680) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.packages(ResourceConfig.java:660) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.micro.base.sidecarbase.RestResourceApplication.<init>(RestResourceApplication.java:16) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375) ~[hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1007) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Francesc\microservices git\sidecar-base\target\sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.getInputStream(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:177) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:87) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        ... 47 common frames omitted

2019-05-02 15:02:46.219 ERROR 17476 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Servlet [jersey-servlet] in web application [] threw load() exception

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Francesc\microservices git\sidecar-base\target\sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.getInputStream(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:177) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:87) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.create(JarZipSchemeResourceFinderFactory.java:65) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.addResourceFinder(PackageNamesScanner.java:282) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.init(PackageNamesScanner.java:198) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:154) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.<init>(PackageNamesScanner.java:110) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.packages(ResourceConfig.java:680) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.packages(ResourceConfig.java:660) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.micro.base.sidecarbase.RestResourceApplication.<init>(RestResourceApplication.java:16) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1375) ~[hk2-utils-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1007) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:975) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1067) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1059) ~[hk2-locator-2.5.0-b32.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342) ~[jersey-server-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.1.jar!/:na]
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4913) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:78) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:264) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:187) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) [spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.0.RELEASE]
        at com.micro.base.sidecarbase.SidecarApplication.main(SidecarApplication.java:13) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [sidecar-base-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

Does anyone know the right way to unpack those jars and that jersey won't have a problem scanning them?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Workaround solution to it.

The class which extends the ResourceConfig class must contain `@Component` annotation, At run time when spring will create the object of that class, it will load the default constructor of that class and then jersey will register all the provided class. But here is a catch, all the class must have `@Component` annotation, else Spring will not able to create the object of that related class and at the end, the jersey will not able to register that class.
 **NOTE:** To register the class in Jersey, use the `register` method, `packages` method is not working in this workaround. 
Do it in this way, no need to Unpacking Jersey libraries in spring boot jar

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ABCJersey extends ResourceConfig {

    public ResourceManagerJersey() {
        // packages("com.currentobject.ABCObject ");
        // packages("com.currentobject.exceptionmapper");

        // Controller-resource layer
        register(ABCResources.class);
        register(ABCCredential.class);

    }

}

@Component("ABCResources ")
@Path("/rm")
public class ABCResources {
----
}
```